# Error when recieving data from a websocket server in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, tcp, esp8266

Im trying to send information from my esp8266 to my python code through a tcp/ip websocket. When I start the code, in the esp serial appears this message:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Host: 192.168.0.67:23
Origin: http://192.168.0.67:23
Sec-WebSocket-Key: P0WRkkqOUSv05V1sTn8Lxw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Connection: Upgrade
```

I dont have any idea of what does that means but up to there the code works normally. The problem is sending data between each other (The esp is the server and the python code is the client) because if I try to send data from python to the esp, the esp wont recieve anything, and when I try to send info from the esp to the python code, the connection closes with this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\toada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\testlel.py", line 3, in <module>
    ws.connect("ws://192.168.0.67:23")
  File "C:\Users\toada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 248, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, url, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Users\toada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 57, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "C:\Users\toada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 146, in _get_resp_headers
    status, resp_headers, status_message = read_headers(sock)
  File "C:\Users\toada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\websocket\_http.py", line 321, in read_headers
    status = int(status_info[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong please? I just want to have the input of the esp as a string

This is the code that I just tested:

```
import websocket

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://echo.websocket.events")
print(ws.recv())
ws.close()
```

And here is the arduino code for the NodeMCU:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2018, circuits4you.com
 * All rights reserved.
 * Create a TCP Server on ESP8266 NodeMCU. 
 * TCP Socket Server Send Receive Demo
*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define SendKey 0  //Button to send data Flash BTN on NodeMCU

int port = 23;  //Port number
WiFiServer server(port);

//Server connect to WiFi Network
const char *ssid = "e";  //Enter your wifi SSID
const char *password = "e";  //Enter your wifi Password

int count=0;
//=======================================================================
//                    Power on setup
//=======================================================================
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SendKey,INPUT_PULLUP);  //Btn to send data
  Serial.println();

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //Connect to wifi
 
  // Wait for connection  
  Serial.println("Connecting to Wifi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {   
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("Open Telnet and connect to IP:");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print(" on port ");
  Serial.println(port);
}
//=======================================================================
//                    Loop
//=======================================================================

void loop() 
{
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  
  if (client) {
    if(client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("Client Connected");
    }
    
    while(client.connected()){      
      while(client.available()>0){
        // read data from the connected client
        Serial.write(client.read()); 
      }
      //Send Data to connected client
      while(Serial.available()>0)
      {
        client.write(Serial.read());
      }
    }
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");    
  }
}
//=======================================================================
```

Comment: The first message is the one that creates the Websocket. You should never see it. Does your ESP really support Websockets? The handshake error suggests it doesn't. Does it even support HTTP?

Comment: Yeah, please edit the question to include the code you're running in the ESP8266 - can't really tell you what's going wrong with it without seeing it. But odds are you're not actually using websockets.

Comment: I uploaded the arduino code

Comment: Well there is nothing there that even handles HTTP, let alone a WebSocket. Use a normal socket at the client.